# How to set a repeated field?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am assigning to a message of proto3 type in a C++ program. The message is something like:

```
message Blah
{
    // some fields

    oneof data
    {
        Foo foo = 6;
    }
}

message Foo
{
    // some fields

    repeated int64 bar = 2;
}
```

I am able to set the non repeating fields, but not sure the idea behind setting the repeated field for example the `bar` field here?

I tried to have a quick glance at the C++ code generated to figure out but it didn't help. If someone can explain the idea behind assigning to the repeated field in cases like these?

Comment: Check out how they populate the `phones` field in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: If you have `Foo foo;`, you can write `foo.add_bar(42);` to add elements one by one. Or you can do `RepeatedField<int64>* bars = foo.mutable_bar();` - this gives you access to `RepeatedField<int64>` representation of the field, which is [a class](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField) somewhat resembling `std::vector`. E.g. it could be assigned from a pair of iterators: `foo.mutable_bar()->Assign(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: Just to note @Mr.Fegur, this particular case is possibly absent in the docs/cpptutorial, they have a `repeated` case but I reckon it's different

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I verified, it worked